# Various forms of overrides

Tags: quiz

**Hi, my friends!**

Sometimes, making an override of a contributed module consists only of: in template.php, copy the function we want to modify and change its prefix "theme" for "my_theme". But this is not enough.

Speaking of the [Quiz](https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz) module:

**1.** I need to modify the multichoice-alternative.tpl.php file. This file contains functions. But, there is only one **foreach**, and within it is what I want to change. How do I override it?

**2.** I need to modify the multichoice.classes.inc file. This file has functions without the prefix "theme". So, I can not replace "theme" for "my_theme" in order to make the override.

Help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy `multichoice-alternative.tpl.php` to your theme's `templates` folder. Make your changes in this file.

In your theme's `template.php` file you are also allowed to create [process and preprocess functions](https://www.drupal.org/node/223430) for any theme function. So, you could create

`function THEME_preprocess_multichoice_alternative(&$variables) {`,

wherein you could add/subtract/alter any variable within `$variables`. This would allow you to pass such variables through to the `multichoice-alternative.tpl.php` file, which in your case now resides in your own theme's `templates` folder.

As to overriding the class, first see if what you need done can be done in the theme layer. If that fails you can always create your own class to inherit from class MultichoiceQuestion, make your changes, then look for the code instantiating instances of the parent class and replace with your own class. And if you do make a note so that when you upgrade the module you can make the changes again.

BTW, it is the norm in Drupal  to put more complex processing (PHP) in the default template process and preprocess functions instead of the template file, and to just put enough processing in the template file to print out the variables and do some conditional logic to assist with that.

Comment: Okay, J. Reynolds. Copy the tpl.php file to the theme's templates folder, it works great.

Regarding extend the class, that seems more complex. Please, do you know any online resource that shows specifically how to do that? A video would be excellent. Or a tutorial for beginners, much better.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [PHP Object Oriented Programming (OOP): Inheritance (4/13)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S3ZMtAFfyTM)

Comment: Pehaps you should firts brush up on [Understanding the hook system for Drupal modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/292) as I suspect that what you want to accomplish can be done via that.

Comment: So is. In fact, with your instructions I can solve my problem. But I want to know how to extend a class.
Thank you. See you soon.